# Как отправить post запрос Postman, Spring

Tags: java, spring, mvc, spring-security, postman

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте, хотел поинтересоваться, как правильно отправить пост запрос на мою регистрацию? Через вопросительный знак в урл не получается

Comment: Код надо текстом приводить, а не картинкой, иначе оно не индексируется поисковиками. По сути вопроса - попробуйте аннотациями рассказать спрингу что у метода регистрации есть ожидаемые параметры у запроса.

Answer (score 0):

POST запрос через вопросительный знак не сможете отправить. [POST запрос защищен, потому что данные не отображаются в строке URL.](https://www.javatpoint.com/get-vs-post) Через знак вопроса и указанные параметры Вы можете получать необходимые данные с сервера и это применительно к GET запросу.